# Changing source code at compilation time (using LLVM)

Tags: llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-ir

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>    
int foo(char* a)
    { char str[10];
      if (strlen(a)<10) 
     { 
       sprintf(str,"Yes");
       puts(str);
       return 0;
     }
     else
     {
       sprintf(str,"No");
       puts(str);
       return 1;
     }
    }
```

Now, lets say while writing a LLVM pass, I want to ensure that instead of calling *sprintf*,  *printf* is called instead (with the same arguments). How could I go about doing that?

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. The prototypes for `sprintf` and `printf` are different. And you're not passing enough arguments to `sprintf` in your example.  What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Fixed it. I would rather have a single printf() replace {sprintf()+puts()} through LLVM pass. I'm trying out LLVM for the first time, was wondering how could one go about doing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a nutshell,

1. Go over all instructions in the function.
2. If the instruction is a `CallInst`, check if it's a call to `sprintf` (you can just check its name).
3. Create a new `CallInst` ([via CallInst::Create)](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1CallInst.html#a8f566e6683d2848e9ba7229bb17a6700) that calls `printf` instead of `sprintf`. I think the easiest way to get the `Value` of the `printf` declaration is to use one of the `Module::getOrCreate` methods. The type of `printf` should be the same as the one for `sprintf` minus the first parameter.
4. Set the operands of the new call instructions to be the same as for `sprintf`, minus the first parameter.
5. Replace the old call with the new call - [`replaceInstWithInst` (in BasicBlockUtils.h)](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/namespacellvm.html#a58cb353f6bb490b0c689f5f2a830414d) is probably the most convenient way.
6. Finally, you might want to track the usages of the old first parameter, remove them all and then remove it - so you'd get rid of that `puts` call.

Answer (score 0):

```
#ifdef USE_BUFFER
#define my_printf(...) sprintf(buffer, __VA_ARGS__)
#else
#define my_printf(...) printf(__VA_ARGS__)
#endif
```

Now you can use for instance `my_printf("My name is %s.", "Bozo");` and it will compile as if it was `printf("My name is %s.", "Bozo")` by default.

If you include `#define USE_BUFFER` before the headers, it will instead convert those lines to `sprintf(buffer, "My name is %s.", "Bozo")` at compile time. Of course the variable `buffer` must exist in the context.

Comment: This requires modification of the source code before compilation, which doesn't seem to me like what the OP was asking for (although this was accepted).